# google apps script のトリガーが前は起動していたの起動しなくなってしまった

Tags: google-apps-script

トリガーを以前１５分毎に起動するように設定していたのですが、現在起動されなくなってしまいました。

[image: トリガー設定]

手動で実行する(矢印ボタン押す)をした時には特に問題なく起動できるのですが、トリガー設定した場合のみまったく動きません。

[image: メニュー]

１つ考えられる原因としては、エラーが頻発していて放置していことが１週間近く続いていた後に、トリガー自体が起動しなくなってしまったように思えます。

どなたかそのような現象発生された方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Comment: 初めまして。
私も突然トリガーが動作しなくなって困っておりました。 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/29025/google%e3%82%b9%e3%83%97%e3%83%ac%e3%83%83%e3%83%89%e3%82%b7%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88-%e3%82%b9%e3%82%af%e3%83%aa%e3%83%97%e3%83%88%e3%82%a8%e3%83%87%e3%82%a3%e3%82%bf%e3%81%a7%e3%83%88%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c%e6%b6%88%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%86 1年以上前の投稿のようですが、現在は解決されていらっしゃるのでしょうか？
もし解決済みでしたら方法を共有いただけると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 3):

> 他のファイルで トリガー 設定したらいきました。 エラーが頻発すると、トリガー制限されるのかもしれません。
>   https://teratail.com/questions/15092

との事です。

Answer (score 1):

エラーに成ったまま放置しているスクリプトは複数ありますがそのようになったケースはありません。
経験上トリガーが動かなくなった(ように見える)パターンは

- スクリプトを何かしら変更したため、権限エラーが発生している
- 対象のスクリプトの実行権限がなくなった

あたりが多いです。
上記2つについてはトリガーが動いているはずなのでエラー通知設定を行っていれば、エラー通知が飛ぶはずです。
エラー通知すら飛んでいない場合は、トリガーの再設定をおすすめします。