# Googleスプレッドシート、スクリプトエディタでトリガーが消えてしまう

Tags: google-apps-script

お世話になります。

Googleスプレッドシートのスクリプトエディタを使っております。

今までは設定したトリガーでcsvファイルのインポートが正しくできていたのですが、数日前（2016年9月上旬）に突然トリガーが動作しなくなりました。

確認したところ、「すべてのトリガー」を見ると、設定しているトリガーが表示されてきますが、薄いグレーで編集が出来ない状態になっていました。

グレーになっているトリガーを削除し、新しいトリガーを設定すると、グレーでは無い状態（黒字）で表示され、編集も可能となりますが、一度スプレッドシートを閉じると、再度グレー状態となり、編集が出来ない状態に変わってしまいます。

時系列で事象をまとめますと、次の通りとなります。

１．トリガーを設定し保存

２．シートを閉じるまでの間は「現在のプロジェクトのトリガー」でチェックすると設定したトリガーが表示される

３．シートを一度閉じて、再度開くと「現在のプロジェクトのトリガー」は「設定されているトリガーはありません」と表示される

４．「すべてのトリガー」を開くと、設定したトリガーが「薄いグレー文字」となっていて編集できない（削除しかできない）状態となっている。（トリガー有効時は黒文字で表示されており、編集も可）

Google Appsのサポートに問い合わせをしたところ、「別のスプレッドシートで試してください」と案内いただいたので、新規でスプレッドシートを作成し試してみましたが、現象は変わりませんでした。

※スクリプトについてはGoogle Appsのサポート対象外ということでこちらのフォーラムを案内いただきました。

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4854 が似ていますね。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。恐らく同様の現象だと思います。しかし、翻訳ツールを使っての解読なので微妙にしかわからないのですが、この問題は未解決状態のようですね。。

Comment: そうですね。難しいバグのようで、Googleの人が6項目の情報提供を求めている状態みたいですね。3) で project key の提供を求めていますから、ここで報告すれば、少なくとも見ては貰えそうですが、どうでしょうね。急ぐ場合は別のアカウントへ移動してみるなどが早いかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。難しいバグなんですね。。　　「別ファイル」は何度も試しましたが、「別アカウント」はまだでした、試してみます！